# Does God become angry?

Tags: allah, anger, mankind

As I understand, God forbade Muslims from becoming angry at one another. So, can Allah become angry **at** a Muslim, even if the anger is not directed at but **for** the Muslim's situation? Shouldn't feeling anger only be an instinct from human nature that we try to overcome, and should not be a nature of God, as he determines our fate after death?

Comment: God has right to do whatever He wants. He gets angry when some of us don’t obey Him. And He gets happy when some of us truly obey Him.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for "God forbidding Muslims from becoming angry at one another"? I have heard of a forbiddance on envy, but not anger. Anger can, after all, be righteous.

Answer (score 3):

Our philosophies for what God should or should not be are irrelevant. God does get angry. It says so in Qur'an:

```
غَيْرِ الْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ - not of those who have evoked Your anger

وَغَضِبَ اللَّـهُ عَلَيْهِ  - Allah has become angry with him
```

His anger like all His other attributes is not like human anger.

```
لَيْسَ كَمِثْلِهِ شَيْءٌ - There is nothing like unto Him
```

This is stated in Al-Aqeedah Al-Tahawiyyah.

> Allah becomes angered and becomes pleased, yet not like anyone else
>   besides Him.

Answer (score -1):

No. G-d does not become angry when you sin. In fact, G-d does not have emotions. G-d is transcendental.

In his commentary on Aristotle’s Ethics, Arab philosopher Abu Nasr al-Farabi wrote that the notion of life after death is plainly wrong: “senseless ravings and old wives’ tales.” Similarly, the highly respected Arab philosopher Averroes criticizes his predecessor, the philosopher Avicenna who felt that G-d is involved in mundane affairs. He disparages Avicenna for abandoning true philosophy and capitulating to the theology of the uneducated masses. Averroes, a contemporary of Maimonides, understands Aristotle to be saying that the world operates in a natural manner. Averroes, like Maimonides, understood that the world functions according to the laws of nature. Averroes and Maimonides were born in the same city, months apart, and although they never met, they would agree with their G-d concept.

Comment: Claims should be supported with references. I doubt that purported claims of Arab philosophers rather than scriptural teachings of Islam are relevant to the site.

Comment: The Arab philosophers were correct. This is how the Qur'an/Bible should be read. You would also check Maimonides as a source on this issue.

Comment: As well as Averroes

Comment: If they were your answer should demonstrate how they were correct. Currently it seems to rely on nothing but appeal to authority, and the people you refer to are far from being accepted based on their name alone.

Comment: @UmH They correct because according to science, natural law is fixed and needs no change. This is the way of the philosophers, the rationalist. They also felt, like modern scientists, that G-d does not interact with humanity. It makes sense.